# Multi listView android

Tags: java, android, adapter

I try create multi ListView but I have `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It seems to be alright.

Main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ActivityObject ao = new ActivityObject();
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                ao.setType("0");
                ao.setTitle("Im null");
            } else {
                ao.setType("1");
                ao.setTitle("Im one");
            }

            dataActivity.add(ao);
        }

        ActivityAdapter adapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataActivity);
        listActivity.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Super Adapter

```
public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ActivityObject> object;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ActivityObject> object) {
        super(context, 0, object);

        this.context = context;
        this.object = object;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {

            if(object.get(position).equals("0")) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_detected, null);
                holder.textActivity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detected_text);
            }

            if(object.get(position).equals("1")) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_people, null);
                holder.textPeople = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people_text);
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //set text
        if(object.get(position).getType().equals("0")) {
            holder.textActivity.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
        }

        if(object.get(position).getType().equals("1")) {
            holder.textPeople.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textActivity;
        public TextView textPeople;
    }
}
```

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at adapters.ActivityAdapter.getView(ActivityAdapter.java:54)
```

this is line 
`convertView.setTag(holder);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee in your code that convertView will not be null:

```
  if(convertView == null) {

        if(object.get(position).equals("0")) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_detected, null);
            holder.textActivity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detected_text);
        }

        if(object.get(position).equals("1")) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_people, null);
            holder.textPeople = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people_text);
        }

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
```

If none of the conditions above hold true, then convertView will still be null. 
Are you sure the conditions are exactly what you want to do?
According to your declaration

```
private ArrayList<ActivityObject> object;
```

object is a list of ActivityObject, but you are comparing them with the *strings* "0" and "1" in

```
object.get(position).equals("0"))
...
object.get(position).equals("1"))
```

Maybe you want to cast them into ActivityObject and the compare the field in type with the strings?

Comment: Aaaaaa... thanks, you are right. I need `object.get(position).getType().equals("1")`. Stupid, stupid error

Answer (score 1):

Move your holder on top. I think it will works. In my opinion you also have to use else statement.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                Log.d("object.get(position) = ", object.get(position));
                if(object.get(position).equals("0")) {
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_detected, null);
                    holder.textActivity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detected_text);
                }
                else if(object.get(position).equals("1")) {
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_people, null);
                    holder.textPeople = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people_text);
                }
                else{
                    //set defualt holder.textPeople here
                }


                convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text
    if(object.get(position).getType().equals("0")) {
        holder.textActivity.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    if(object.get(position).getType().equals("1")) {
        holder.textPeople.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but its not work. I have error in this line `convertView.setTag(holder);`

Comment: look now. This bug occurs when converView it's null. Maybe object.get(position) it's not equls "0" or "1" then your convert view is null because you don;t use else statements. Please debug it.

Comment: Thanks, it had do like this `object.get(position).getType().equals("1")` and its work )

Answer (score 1):

**Replace yours adapter with these code**

```
public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ActivityObject> object;
LayoutInflater vi;

ViewHolder holder;

public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ActivityObject> object) {
    super(context, 0, object);

    this.context = context;
    this.object = object;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();;

    if(convertView == null) {

        if(object.get(position).equals("0")) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_detected, null);
            holder.textActivity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detected_text);
        }

        if(object.get(position).equals("1")) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_activity_people, null);
            holder.textPeople = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people_text);
        }


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text
    if(object.get(position).getType().equals("0")) {
        holder.textActivity.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    if(object.get(position).getType().equals("1")) {
        holder.textPeople.setText(object.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textActivity;
    public TextView textPeople;
    }
   }
```

Comment: i copy this code and past in my adapter. But i have some error `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException` in line `convertView.setTag(holder);`

Comment: Thanks, it had do like this `object.get(position).getType().equals("1")` and its work )